# Drawing Controls Guidelines?

Tags: c++, qt, styling

I was wondering how Qt does all its styling. I need to create a custom control and I'd like for it to meet the standards such that my control won't feel out of place on different platforms and styles.

For example, I'm going to need a cursor that's used in text, does Qt provide a method for drawing it? And how would I go about implementing it such that I don't redraw the entire widget for the blinking of the cursor?

Answer (score 1):

What you typically do to create custom widgets is two-folded:

- combine existing widgets
- derive from existing widgets

That means, e.g., if you want to create a custom text input widget, use an existing one and only change the parts you need to change in overloads. Or maybe your customization does not need to change the text input part at all, but just plug it in at the right place. The widget I am talking about right now is `QLineEdit`. It is actually very basic and customizable.

There actually exist two methods (at least) on how to combine widgets to form your custom one. The first is to create a .ui file and use it in your custom class (or create widgets in code). The second one is to use a `QGraphicsScene`. There you can combine freehand painting (`QPainter`), with customly positioned objects and fully-fledged widgets.

If it is too hard to solve your problem by combining widgets and/or deriving from them, the last resort is always to take an existing widget with the desired functionality (e.g. `QLineEdit` that has a text-edit cursor) and read/copy the code (Note: license issues may arise).

To give a better answer to your question we would need more details on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: None of this actually answers the question of styling custom controls :(

Comment: Well as an example, I need to draw the background just like QLineEdit, and behave just like it. I could just use the painter and draw a rectangle with a border box but that will not suffice for any other theme. The color of text is another example, the color of text should match everything else when the user is selecting the text of the custom control or when the control is disabled it should have a specific color.

Comment: Well you just do not start with drawing the box yourself. The theme engine does that for you. How you invoke the theme engine you find in the source code of QLineEdit. But it is a pain and you will fail to keep up with updates and fixes. You really should use existing widgets. For colors, you can use QPalette. You call palette() on your parent widget to get it and then you have all the colors you should use at your disposal.

Comment: That's a bit of a let down, I guess I'll draw my box then... Any suggestion on how to handle the cursor ? I've found there's pixelMetric with "PM_TextCursorWidth" to get the cursor width, though if I am going to draw it on my own, how would I draw the blinking of the cursor without invoking a repaint ? Or does Qt redraw the entire widget for the blinking... in which case that seems quite expensive.

Comment: You call update() with the damaged region (i.e., the region that needs to be redrawn) as a parameter.